# Grails httpbuilder json response

Tags: json, grails, httpbuilder

Having a few issues with the response handling of my httpbuilder post and json

within my service I have:

```
def jsonDataToPost = '{"accountNumber" : ' + accNo + ',"accountName" : ' + accName + '}'

            def http = new HTTPBuilder('https://myurl.com/dataInput')
            def jsonResponse
            http.auth.basic ('username','password')
            http.request(POST, ContentType.JSON) {
                headers.'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
                body = jsonDataToPost
                response.success = { json ->
                    println("Success")
                    jsonResponse = json
                }
                response.failure = { json ->
                    println("Fail")
                    jsonResponse = json
                }
            }
```

firstly for some reason the code actually skips out rather than completing and so I'm not getting the jsonReponse I'm after but I can't figure out why? If I reponse my response.success/fail and I post correct data my json post works but again I still get no json back

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
       def requestData = [foo:bar]
       http.request(POST, ContentType.JSON) {
            headers.'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
            body = (requestData as JSON).toString()
            response.success = { resp, reader ->
                println("Success")
                jsonReponse = reader.text
            }
            response.failure = { resp, reader ->
                println("Failed, status: " + resp.status)
                jsonReponse = reader.text
            }
        }
```

Comment: my request seems to be tripping out on the response.success line? thanks

Comment: updated with minor adjustment to how data is converted to JSON as string

Comment: thanks for your help raffian. The error was actually being caused by the server not responding correctly and so I was sent on a bit of a chase... fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Grails 3.x you can use `http-builder-ng`
https://http-builder-ng.github.io/http-builder-ng